# Ruby: can the following array be generated with a one-liner using the step function: [1, 10, 100, 1_000, 10_000, 100_000, 1_000_000]

Tags: ruby

I have thought of a couple of different ways to generate the following array: `[1, 10, 100, 1_000, 10_000, 100_000, 1_000_000]`

It seems like it might be possible to generate this array with the `step` function in an elegant manner, but I was not able to figure it out.  Something that passes in a second argument to the `step` function and says you want the last value times 10:

```
0.step(1_000_000, ???).to_a
```

Here are the solutions I have come up with so far:

I don't really like the `inject` solution because I would prefer to specify `1_000_000` as the upper bound:

```
(0..6).inject([]) { |memo, number| memo << 10**number; memo }
```

This is the ugly `step` solution I came up with:

```
result = []
0.step(6) {|number| result << 10 ** number}
result
```

A `while` loop does not feel right either, but at least it lets me specify the upper_bound (instead of Math.log10(upper_bound)):

```
result = [1]
while result.last < 1_000_000
  result << result.last * 10
end
result
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Your username is so beautifully appropriate :)

Comment: In your inject() block, << returns memo already.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about this?

```
0.upto(Math.log10(1_000_000)).map { |i| 10**i }
```

It's only going to properly work for powers of 10, but it lets you specify the upper bound, and then computes the powers of 10 to iterate through.

If you want to lead with the upper bound, you can do so easily via:

```
Math.log10(10_000_000).to_i.downto(0).map {|i| 10 ** i }.reverse
```

If terseness is really important, you can always reopen Fixnum with a generalized solution:

```
class Fixnum
  def by_powers_of(base = 10)
    0.upto(Math.log(self, base)).map {|i| base ** i }
  end
end

10_000_000.by_powers_of(10)
# => [1, 10, 100, 1000, 10000, 100000, 1000000, 10000000]

(64**2).by_powers_of(2)
# => [1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64, 128, 256, 512, 1024, 2048, 4096]
```

Comment: You are missing the last number since `log10` returns 6.

Comment: Doh, thanks. As they say, there are two hard problems in computer science: cache invalidation, naming things, and off-by-one errors.

Answer (score 7):

You had many solutions. What about using `map` this way.

```
7.times.map { |i| 10**i }
#=> [1, 10, 100, 1000, 10000, 100000, 1000000]
```

If you want to set the upper bound you could always to something like this

```
1_000_000.to_s.size.times.map { |i| 10**i }
#=> [1, 10, 100, 1000, 10000, 100000, 1000000]
```

Comment: The OP is wanting to specify the upper bound in the expression (`1_000_000` in this case).

Comment: @mbratch Isn't `6` the upper bound here?

Comment: `1_000_000` is the upper bound. `6` is just one way to compute it (via `10**1_000_000`). The problem description says: *I don't really like the `inject` solution because I would prefer to specify 1_000_000 as the upper bound:*

Comment: Could always take a logarithm if that *needs* to be the upper bound.

Comment: @minitech the OP indicated he preferred not to use `Math.log10` (*... at least it lets me specify the upper_bound (instead of Math.log10(upper_bound))*). The `to_s.size` is a clever way to get the log without using the math lib. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
class Integer

  def powers_upto(max)
    results = []
    exp = 0

    loop do
      result = self**exp
      break if result > max
      results << result
      exp += 1
    end

    results
  end

end



p 10.powers_upto(1_000_000)
p 2.powers_upto(11)

--output:--
[1, 10, 100, 1000, 10000, 100000, 1000000]
[1, 2, 4, 8]
```